# Angular HostBinding in a custom directive not working inside an *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular2-hostbinding

I have created a custom directive that adds / removes a class selector with a click event. Should be pretty straight forward, and it works fine as long as I'm using the directive outside an ngFor loop.
The directive is composed of the code below:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[appFav]'
})
export class FavDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.isFav') isFav:boolean = false;

    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
        this.isFav = !this.isFav;
        console.log('clicked');
    }
    @Input() set appFav(val:boolean) {
        this.isFav = val;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to use that directive on a button inside a Cards component.
So inside the Cards Component's html template the buttons code looks like that:

```
<div class="favBtn" appFav><span class="material-icons">favorite_border</span></div>
```

This works when I'm using the  component on its own, but when I generate multiple cards using the ngFor loop like below the decorator doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
<custom-card class="card" *ngFor="let card of getCards()"></custom-card>
```

The isFav property in the directive is fixed and the .isFav class selector is not added when I inspect the button. Though the console.log messages display properly which means that the onClick method in the directive does run.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried without ngfor using  2 instance manually in a page if that is working ?

Comment: hey it's working fine , i just checked it's adding class  isFav ,

Comment: It works fine when I create the 2 instances manually, however the instances created using the ngFor loop are not interacting properly.
I event tried it in a brand new project, still got the same problem.
Note that the instances are created with their corresponding classes properly, however the click event doesn't change them.

Comment: I am sharing the app on
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uux4nw
. Notice that the styling of the toggle button on the first two cards works properly, while the buttons on the cards created by the ngFor are not working
Thanks a lot @LogicBlower

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Right now angular is not able to differentiate b/w components if you see elements panel you click on a button all the instance get updated. so to assign a unique key to all the elements in loop so that angular can differentiate them.

--Try below code you will get expected behavior:

in you **app.component.html**  -- Add a **trackBy** that function will assign unique key

```
  <app-media-item *ngFor="let mi of getMediaItems(); trackBy:trackBytitle"
                  [mediaItem]='mi'
                  (interact)='hdlMediaItem($event)' 
  >
  </app-media-item>
```

and in you **app.component.ts** -- right now title seems unique to me so i return title part.

```
trackBytitle(index: number, mediaObj: any): string {
return mediaObj.title; // title is unique or return something unique 
}
```